# Labeling Rows Based on Time Difference from Flagged Row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to compare different trends as they relate to the same type of event. I have labeled the event and consider it to be time 0. The timestamp increases by 1 second for each row. Here's some sample data:

```
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1589359698, 1589359699, 
1589359700, 1589359701, 1589359702, 1589359703, 1589359704, 1589359705, 
1589359706, 1589359707, 1589359708, 1589359709, 1589359710, 1589359711, 
1589359712, 1589359713, 1589359714, 1589359715, 1589359716, 1589359717, 
1589359718, 1597392790, 1597392791, 1597392792, 1597392793, 1597392794, 
1597392795, 1597392796, 1597392797, 1597392798, 1597392799, 1597392800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), time_from_event= c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), measurement = c(11.27387375, 
11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 
11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.3522525, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 
11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.41321375, 11.3174175, 
11.3174175, 11.3174175, 11.195495, 11.30870875, 11.2129125, 11.3, 
11.404505, 11.23903875, 11.23903875, 11.23903875, 11.3522525, 
11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375, 11.27387375
)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Everything before the event should be labeled with increasing negative numbers, i.e., the reading taken 1s before the event should be -1, the reading taken 2s before the event should be -2, etc.

Everything after the event should be labeled with increasing numbers, i.e., 1s after the event is 1, 2s after the event is 2, etc.

The two different days are grouped separately. The end result is something like this where each day has the rows labeled leading up to and away from the event:

```
timestamp            | time_from_event | reading
--------------------------------------------------
2020-05-13 08:48:18  |        -5       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:19  |        -4       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:20  |        -3       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:21  |        -2       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:22  |        -1       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:23  |         0       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:24  |         1       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:25  |         2       |  11.27387      
2020-05-13 08:48:26  |         3       |  11.35225      
2020-05-13 08:48:27  |         4       |  11.27387
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped by the `Date` converted 'timestamp', take the difference between the `row_number` and the position index of '0' value in 'time_from_event'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(day = as.Date(timestamp)) %>%
    mutate(time_new = row_number() - match(0, time_from_event)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 32 x 5
#   timestamp           time_from_event measurement day        time_new
#   <dttm>                        <dbl>       <dbl> <date>        <int>
# 1 2020-05-13 08:48:18              NA        11.3 2020-05-13       -5
# 2 2020-05-13 08:48:19              NA        11.3 2020-05-13       -4
# 3 2020-05-13 08:48:20              NA        11.3 2020-05-13       -3
# 4 2020-05-13 08:48:21              NA        11.3 2020-05-13       -2
# 5 2020-05-13 08:48:22              NA        11.3 2020-05-13       -1
# 6 2020-05-13 08:48:23               0        11.3 2020-05-13        0
# 7 2020-05-13 08:48:24              NA        11.3 2020-05-13        1
# 8 2020-05-13 08:48:25              NA        11.3 2020-05-13        2
# 9 2020-05-13 08:48:26              NA        11.4 2020-05-13        3
#10 2020-05-13 08:48:27              NA        11.3 2020-05-13        4
# … with 22 more rows
```